# Getting Theme element into plugins page editor in wp admin

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-options, visual-editor

I'm having a hardtime integrating a theme editing element (in default page/post editor in wp-admin) into page/post editor made by the plugin [BU Versions](https://github.com/bu-ist/bu-versions).

Basicly I need this theme element

> [image: theme element]

to get in the plugin editor

> [image: plugin editor]

I've been googling and the only thing I found that could be relevant was [this plugin wiki](https://github.com/bu-ist/bu-versions/wiki/Adding-Post-Meta-Support-for-Alternate-Versions).

I don't really know what to do with that since I know only HTML, CSS and some Javascript atm, and don't know where to look.

Comment: In the theme, you need to locate the code responsible for that box (use some html element name to find it in the PHP code), but it looks like it's using the action hook `edit_form_after_title`.